# Solve ODE $2yy''+(y')^2+(y')^4=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution of the ODE: 
>   $$ 2yy''+(y')^2+(y')^4=0.$$

*Attempt.*  I tried substitution $y=e^z$, but it got me nowhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)#Second_order).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt.  Note that 
$$y''=y'\frac{dy'}{dy}.$$
So, the DE becomes
$$2yy'\frac{dy'}{dy}+(y')^2+(y')^4=0.$$
That is, $y'=0$ (which gives $y(x)=k$ for some constant $k$), or
$$2y\frac{dy'}{dy}+y'\big(1+(y')^2\big)=0.$$
So,
$$-\frac{2\ dy'}{y'\big(1+(y')^2\big)}=\frac{dy}{y}.$$
By integrating this equation, we obtain
$$\ln\left(\frac{1+(y')^2}{(y')^2}\right)=\ln(cy)$$
for some constant $c$.  So,
$$cy-1=\frac{1}{(y')^2}.$$
That is,
$$y'=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{cy-1}}.$$
Thus,
$$\sqrt{cy-1}\ dy=\pm dx.$$
By integrating the equation above, we obtain
$$\frac{2}{3c}(cy-1)^{\frac32}=\pm(x-a)$$
for some constant $a$.  That is,
$$y(x)=\frac{1+\left(\frac{3c}{2}(x-a)\right)^{\frac23}}{c}$$
is another form of solutions (apart from the constant functions).

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the equation (assuming $y'\ne 0$, $y=C=const.$ also being solutions) to
$$
-\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{2y'y''}{y'^2(1+y'^2)}=\frac{2y''}{y'}-\frac{2y'y''}{1+y'^2}
$$
which integrates to
$$
-\ln|y|+c=2\ln|y'|-\ln(1+y'^2)\\~\\
\implies 1+y'^{-2}=Cy,~~\sqrt{Cy-1}\,y'=\pm 1,~~\sqrt{Cy-1}^3=\pm\frac32Cx+D
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ 2yy''+(y')^2+(y')^4=0.$$
The usual change of function to solve an ODE of autonomous kind is :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y)$$
$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(y)f(y)$
$$2yf'f+f^2+f^4=0 $$
This is a separable ODE.
$$\frac{dy}{y}=-2\frac{df}{f+f^3}$$
$$y=c_1\left(1+\frac{1}{f^2}\right)$$
$f=\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{y-c_1}}\quad;\quad\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{y-c_1}}.\quad$ Again a separable ODE.
$$x=\int \sqrt{\frac{y-c_1}{c_1}}dy$$
After elementary calculus :
$$y(x)=c_1+c_1\left(\frac{3}{2c_1}(x+c_2)\right)^{2/3}$$

Comment: +1 why did you delete your answer it was quiet right no ?

Comment: @Isham. In fact, the same answer was posted  two times. I couldn't understand how this happened. So, I was compelled to delete one of them.when I realised the mistake.

Comment: It happens sometimes ..